# The logic behind creating FETCH_HEADs

Tags: git

I don't understand the logic behind creating FETCH_HEADs in some cases - example:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.2.5

$ git fetch aarep       
From ../aa
 * [new branch]      master     -> aarep/master
 * [new branch]      skin       -> aarep/skin
## Fair enough, creating FETCH_HEADs here wouldn't help


$ git fetch aarep master
From ../aa
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
## Instead of creating a remote tracker, git creates a FETCH_HEAD. No problem.

$ git fetch aarep master skin
From ../aa
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * branch            skin       -> FETCH_HEAD
## What's the point of creating FETCH_HEADs here - only one would survive ?!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the contents of FETCH_HEAD after your last example. Both refs are there, perhaps something like:

```
b0d66b5110faaeb395610ba43b6eb70a18ab5e25        branch 'master' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
a9004c5cb2204cf950debab328e86de5eefb9da4        branch 'next' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
```

It's not overwritten.

For what it's worth, here's a use of this functionality in `git-pull`, which is implemented as a shell script:

```
merge_head=$(sed -e '/  not-for-merge   /d' \
    -e 's/  .*//' "$GIT_DIR"/FETCH_HEAD | \
    tr '\012' ' ')
```

Comment: Very interesting. But then if I do 'git merge FETCH_HEAD' I'm not given a choice between the two - so do I only have access to the head of the FETCH_HEAD (so it's not over-written but in practice is) or is there some other rule. I know we're now wandering on the edge of practicality.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there are tools that will actually let you loop over its contents, or if you have to do it manually - presumably it does this largely in order to support `git-pull`.

Answer (score 3):

I like to pretend that `git fetch` is a back-end (plumbing) command.

The one argument form of `git fetch`, which takes just a remote, is an old, deprecated name for `git remote update`, which does the same thing.

The two-plus argument form, which takes a remote and a list of branches, is the actual back-end implementation of everything else.  It's exposed as it's occasionally useful, if you know what you're doing, or scripting things.  An example use would be if you want to inspect a branch before fetching it properly.

Imagine `git fetch origin` (like `git remote update`) does basically:

`git ls-remote origin` to find out what branches are available on `origin`.  Then, for each branch found (that matches the fetch spec, which defaults to "all branches"):

1. `git fetch origin thatbranch`, to do the low-level fetch.
2. `git branch -f origin/thatbranch FETCH_HEAD` to move your "remote tracking branch" (your local copy of the remote branch) to that `FETCH_HEAD`.

You're free to do this by hand, removing the need for `git fetch`'s one-argument case, and for `git remote update` (the even higher level). Obviously this wouldn't be very convenient.

Comment: This is mostly beside the point. I think the OP is aware of how you can use git-fetch, and is just asking about why it would fetch one ref and store it in FETCH_HEAD only to overwrite it with another.

Comment: Yes I was under the impression FETCH_HEAD is like an atomic pointer.